# How to know the previous controller and action , you come from it , in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have  a project in Laravel 5 , I want to record in my database the time which user leave some pages in it, so how can I know which controller and action user come from ?

Comment: Did you try googling it?

Comment: I only found method to know which controller & action I'm in , not which controller & action I'm come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record the history of requests made by each user in their session. Then when a new request comes in, you'll have access to all the previous requests.

Another less-volatile alternative, since you state you want to store this information in a database, is to go ahead and directly store each request made by users in your database. You can then analyze it however you want offline or in your controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot , It's a great idea